# How can I selectively colour the entire area of a plot based on specified points on the x-axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to colour the background of a line plot based on manually inserted coordinates on the x-axis.

As a simple example:

```
x <- 1:10
y <- c(2.0,2.0,2.1,2.2,2.4,2.7,2.7,2.8,2.8,2.9)
df <- data.frame(x,y)
library(ggplot2)
plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_line()
print(plot)
```

Now I would like to colour the entire area of the plot between two specified points on the x-axis, say, between 1.5 and 3. Would anyone happen to know an easy manual solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for. You could use a `geom_rect` to achieve this:

```r
x <- 1:10
y <- c(2.0,2.0,2.1,2.2,2.4,2.7,2.7,2.8,2.8,2.9)
df <- data.frame(x,y)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_rect(xmin = 1.5, xmax = 3, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = "red", inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>